# Laravel Auth::user() with custom logged in user

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a legacy system that I built years ago with Laravel 5 that used md5 to encrypt passwords. I would like to use Laravel Passport to make an api, since the frontend app is moving to React and the backend will be a Laravel 7 api app, but I don't think the Auth::attempt() will work since the password didn't use Hash.

Can I customize the ::attempt() to check for md5 for the password or customize Auth::user() to accept a custom user so I can generate an accessToken? I've been looking at the docs and I don't see anyway to do it.

Comment: Just a stupid question, are you porting the L5 app to a L7 app? Or are you just updating the existing application to it's latest version and debug the hell out of it?

Comment: Rebuilding the application in L7 but have legacy user database

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own guard or provider:

- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards (I think you need this one)
- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers

You could use the `Auth::viaRequest` as explained on this page: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#closure-request-guards

```php
Auth::viaRequest('custom-token', function ($request) {
    return User::query()->where('password', md5($request->password))->first();
});
```

BTW: You should move to a better hashing of your passwords ;)